# Is there a stable plugin for Jenkins for running builds on VMs?

Tags: jenkins, virtualbox, travis-ci

Travis CI has a really nice feature, builds are run within VirtualBox VMs. Each time a build is started, the box is refreshed from a snapshot and the code copied on to it. Any problems with the build cannot affect the host, and you can use any OS to run your builds on.

This would be really good, for example, compiling and testing code on a guest OS that matches your production env. Also, you can keep your host free of any installation dependencies you might need (e.g. a database server) and run ITs without worrying about things like port conflicts.

Does such a thing exist for Jenkins?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the Vagrant Plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Vagrant-plugin

This plugin allows booting of Vagrant virtual machines, provisioning them and also executing scripts inside of them

Answer (score 4):

You can run Jenkins in a Master Slave Setup. Your Master instance manages all the jobs but lets all the slaves do the actual work. These Slaves can be VMs or physical machines. Go To Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> New Node to add Nodes to your Jenkins Setup.

Comment: One option that gives me is to set-up the VM before the build start using a pre-build step, and tear it down when done. Thanks!

Comment: I understand, in this case this solution won't help.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [vSphere Cloud Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/vSphere+Cloud+Plugin) and the [Scripted Cloud Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scripted+Cloud+plugin) that can be used for this purpose.